# Meaning of a semicolon in lambda expression

Tags: haskell, lambda, syntax

**Type:**

```
data Command a = Command String (a -> IO a)
```

**Function:**

```
iofunc_ :: String -> (a -> IO ()) -> Command a
iofunc_ s f = Command s (\x -> do f x ; return x)
```

What does the semicolon do in the lambda expression `(\x -> do f x ; return x)`?

Comment: It's part of the `do`-notation, not the lambda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They just separate the two expression `f x` and `return x` in do notation. In fact these all are equivalent in your case:

```
iofunc_ s f = Command s (\x -> do f x ; return x)

iofunc_ s f = Command s (\x -> do {f x ; return x})

iofunc_ s f = Command s (\x -> do f x
                                  return x)

iofunc_ s f = Command s (\x -> f x >> return x)
```

Comment: When can you omit the curly braces? I always thought they were mandatory if you made the semicolon explicit.

Comment: @kqr Didn't read the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) fully, but you can see that's what they have demonstrated in the example with `let`.

Answer (score 4):

Semicolon anywhere is equivalent to a change of line indented to the same level as the previous valid expression.

I saw it by going through how indentation works (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).